# How to control reserved capacity of numpy array?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy

In C++ `vector` there is `.reserve(size)` and `.capacity()` methods which allow you to reserve memory for array and get current reserved size. This reserved size is greater or equal to vector's real size (obtained through `.size()`).

If I do `.push_back(element)` in this array memory for array is not reallocated if current `.size() < .capacity()`. This allows to fast appending elements to array. If there is no more capacity then array gets reallocated to new memory location and all data is copied.

I'd like to know if there are same low-level methods available for `numpy` arrays? Can I reserve large capacity so that small appends/inserts don't reallocate numpy array in memory to often?

Probably there is already some growth mechanism built into numpy array, like 10% growth of reserved capacity on each reallocation. But I wonder if I can control this by myself and maybe implement faster growth, like doubling reserved capacity on each growth.

Also would be nice to know if there `in-place` variants of numpy functions, like insert/append, which modify array in-place without creating a copy. I.e. part of array is somehow reserved and filled with zeros and this part is used for shifting. E.g. if I have array `[1 0 0 0]` with 3 last 0 elements reserved then in-place `.append(2)` would modify mutably this array to make `[1 2 0 0]` with 2 reserved 0 elements left. Then `.insert(1, 3)` would again modify it to become `[1 3 2 0]` with 1 reserved 0 element left. I.e. everything like in `C++`.

Comment: *"Probably there is already some growth mechanism built into numpy array, like 10% growth of reserved capacity on each reallocation."*  No, there is not.  NumPy arrays have a fixed size.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Are you sure that you are speaking about reserved capacity and not `.size` of array? Because if there is no reservation it means that if I have 1GB huge array and append 1 element to it then whole 1GB is reallocated and copied. Sure that this is the case? There should be some at least small growth mechanism.

Comment: Pyrhon `list` has a growth mechanism like this, and a decent `append` method. `numpy` does not.  *Do not*  use `np.append` in such a way.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm using `np.insert()`. Of cause I don't process by 1 number in a loop. I do process around 16 million numbers per loop, which is very huge, but totally there are billions of numbers to crunch, aggregate and store. So total array is gigabytes in size. Hence inserting even 16 million numbers in each loop and reallocating several gigabytes is not efficient. If I could control growth, it will reallocate very rarely.

Comment: `np.insert` makes a whole new array.  Its code is python, so you can see for yourself.

Comment: @hpaulj Do you know if there is in-place version of insert/append? That can do no reallocation, but only shifting data towards the end?